# Is it possible to use an array without initializing it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen some code from Stack Overflow. It confused me a lot. I just don't know whether some part is missing or not.

The code is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init($captcha_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 

$out2['result'] = curl_exec($ch);
$out2['error']  = curl_error($ch);
$out2['info']   = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I know `$Out2['result']` is assigned here and result is the key and `curl_exec($ch)` is value here. But i haven't seen `$out2` declared as an array ?

Is this missing from this code or can we apply like this ?

Comment: See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, **yes**.

PHP isn't (at the moment) that explicit about declaring data types when creating variables - unlike other languages, although I'm sure PHP are changing their ways.

Although you can do this, it's advised (good practice) to declare the data type of the variable before assigning value(s) to it.

Comment: so $out2 is not declaired as array ..is that missing here in this code ?

Comment: From what you've provided, it's not declared as an array explicitly - but it's treated like one. If you look at other languages, such as VB.NET with `Option Explicit On` (probably a better example out there somewhere), you'll understand why PHP is "frowned upon" with this much freedom of manipulating variable types without declaring their type beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

When a value is first assigned to `$out2`, it is initialized as whatever datatype in needs to be. In this case, an array.

Comment: so $out2 is not declaired as array ..is that missing here in this code ?

Comment: @william: It's a *good practice* to initialize the array beforehand. But it is *not* a requirement.