# how to add an array to a session php

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

I want to add different stuffs to costumers cart but before adding the stuff transition in the database costumer must pay and then redirect to another page after Successful transition i need the chosen stuffs id's i tried using `$_POST` but the browser does not send the post value because of payment system in the middle i tried using sessions instead 
I want to add array of `integers` to a session control i already tried using this code

```
$t=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_SESSION['exam_id']=$t
```

I don't know if i can do such a thing or not but what is the parallels

Comment: Did you start session before using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: definitely yes i started the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you specified is working correctly. Sessions can hold arrays.

The session superglobal is an represented as an array itself within PHP, so you can just get and set values by doing the following

**Setting:**

`$_SESSION['exam_id'][] = "new value";`

or

`$_SESSION['exam_id'] = array("new value", "another value");`

**Getting:**

`$_SESSION['exam_id'][0]; // returns a value`

This returns the first value in the exam_id array within the session variable

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start the session. Make your code;

```
<?php
session_start();
$t = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_SESSION['exam_id'] = $t;
```

- You need [**`session_start()`**](https://www.php.net/session_start)
- You didn't have a semi-colon `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you can use array in session like this..

1. you have to start session with `session_start();`
2. and then store your array to session `$_SESSION['items'][] = $item;`

and then you use it, whenever you want:

```
foreach($_SESSION['items'][] as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Your code will throw an error about the undefined index $_SESSION['items'].. You will have to set that array first like: `$_SESSION['items'] = [];` or `$_SESSION['items'] = array();` (if you like oldskool)

Comment: @DamienOvereem oldskool, maybe... but also for versions before 5.4

Comment: @ManojSonagra It's not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633000/is-it-possible-to-use-an-array-without-initializing-it/21633074#21633074

Comment: It -is- neccesary. You might not notice it because you have notices disabled. Enable notices and you'll be flooded with "Undefined index" notices. It's best practice. Ofcourse you can disable notices and pretend like not defining indexes is a good idea, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set PHP sessions equal to an array just like you're doing.

To set the `$_SESSION` variable equal to all POST data, you can do this:

`$_SESSION['exam_id'] = $_POST;`

Be sure to add `session_start()` prior to declaring any session variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_SESSION['exam_id'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['exam_id'],$t[0]);
array_push($_SESSION['exam_id'],$t[1]);
array_push($_SESSION['exam_id'],$t[2]);
array_push($_SESSION['exam_id'],$t[3]);
array_push($_SESSION['exam_id'],$t[4]);
```